# sed, delete from MarkA up to but not include MarkB

Tags: linux, unix, sed, text-editing

Expression in math term, I'd like to delete a region of `[MarkA,MarkB)`. I.e., the deletion happens right when the keyword `MarkA` is encountered, all the way to keyword `MarkB`, but not including that line (the line including  `MarkB` keyword is left untouched).

Is it possible to do so in `sed`?

Say my `MarkA` is `^3`, and `MarkB` is `7`,

```
$ seq 9 | sed '/^3/,/7/d'
1
2
8
9
```

It will get my `7` deleted but I want to preserve it.

To be more precise, I can accurately locate `MarkA` (e.g. `^3`), but I want to delete up to the first `MarkB`. I.e.,

```
seq 19 | sed '/^3/,/7/d'
```

*is* what I'm looking for if the `7` line is not deleted.

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking, but can you give a concrete example? It can be made up, but a sample input and the expected output.

Comment: https://github.com/choroba/small-scripts/blob/master/betw

Comment: @choroba, almost, but I want do *delete* them but preserve the rest. your script just preserve them but delete the rest.

Comment: @xpt: That's why I only commented, not answered your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using sed

This deletes the range up to but not including the last line in the range:

```
$ seq 9 | sed '/^3/,/7/{/7/p;d}'
1
2
7
8
9
```

As before, `/^3/,/7/` selects the whole range, inclusive of `/7/`.  And, as before, that range gets deleted with the `d` command.  However, before we delete, we check to see if the line contains `/7/` and, in that case, we print it with the `p` command.

#### Using awk

awk offers much flexibility. Here, we use a variable `f` as a flag to decide if lines should be printed:

```
$ seq 9 | awk '/^3/{f=1} /7/{f=0} !f'
1
2
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed's predecessor, `ed`, if you have the data in a file:

```
seq 9 > data
printf '%s\n' '/^3/,/7/-1 d' 'wq' | ed -s data
cat data
1
2
7
8
9
```

The command breaks down like this:

- `printf` -- send two strings down the pipe; those two strings have a newline appended to them so that they appear as commands to `ed`. The two commands are:

  - `/^3/,/7/-1 d` -- in the range /^3/ to one before /7/, delete the lines
  - `wq` -- write the file back to disk and quit
- `ed -s data` -- run `ed` in silent mode, so that it does not report the number of bytes written at the end.

The core useful feature here is `ed`'s ability to use addition or subtraction after the range regular expression. The [(GNU) ed manpage](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html#Line-addressing) describes it here:

> A line address is constructed as follows:

...

> Addresses can be followed by one or more address offsets, optionally separated by whitespace. Offsets are constructed as follows:

> '+' or '-' followed by a number adds or subtracts the indicated number of lines to or from the address.

> '+' or '-' not followed by a number adds or subtracts 1 to or from the address.

> A number adds the indicated number of lines to the address.